Upgrading issue fixes for Ubuntu 24.04 from 22.04: Update-Manager, Missing UI, and PipeWire Solutions
Issue 1 - update-manager:
During the upgrade to Ubuntu 24.04, I encountered the following issue:
The package 'update-manager' is marked for removal but it is in the removal deny list.


Fixes for this issue in the answer section.

Issue 2 - No UI After Upgrade:
After the upgrade, the system only booted into the CLI, with no graphical user interface (UI). To resolve this, I attempted to reinstall the desktop environment:
sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop

However, this resulted in the following package conflict error related to libpipewire:
libspa-0.2-modules: version 1.0.7-3~ubuntu 22.04 is to be installed


Fixes for this issue in the answer section.


Fix for issue 1 - update-manager:

Remove the old version of update-manager: sudo apt remove update-manager.

Reinstall update-manager: sudo apt install update-manager.


Fix for Issue 2 - No UI After Upgrade:
Remove the conflicting libspa-0.2-modules package:
sudo apt remove --purge libspa-0.2-modules

Update package lists and upgrade the system:
sudo apt update
sudo apt full-upgrade

